# kernel: dmi: Firmware registration failed on VPS

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running  Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.8.0-58-generic x86_64) on a KVM VPS server.

Can anyone tell me the meaning of these two lines in my journal?

```
Apr 01 05:42:34 vps1 kernel: dmi: Firmware registration failed.
Apr 01 05:42:35 vps1 acpid[349]: cannot open input layer
```

Do those indicate issues I need to solve? Or can they be ignored?

cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#UserTasksMax=12288
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 'errors' are both benign and are indicative of a PVM (Para-virtualized Machine) as opposed to a HVM (Hardware Virtualized Machine).

A linux kernel stores information from the BIOS in its DMI (Desktop Management Information) tables.  There's quite a lot of useful information there.  From your Dom0 or from a HVM, run:

```
sudo dmidecode
```

and you'll see all of the information available.  This information is sometimes referred to as SMBIOS (System Management BIOS).

A PVM does not have direct access to the hardware, so during the boot ACPI is disabled and the kernel will make note of the fact that it has no DMI data.  Your logs will also contain a line like:

```
kernel: ACPI in unprivileged domain disabled
```